# How to Resize iOS UI component same as Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm working on a **iOS** app where in a screen, user can have multiple `UI component`. Also, user can **drag and reposition** those component.
Now, I want all **UI component** to be **resized** by user through finger touch(same as we can resize in Interface Builder with mouse).

**EDIT:**
  [image]

As above screen shot of **IB**, we can hold any tiny squares around button with mouse and resize the button.Same thing I need to implement in my App by finger gesture (probably by `UIPanGestureRecognizer`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thanks to this [Beautiful Example](https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView), I'm able to achieve what I wanted to.
Now I am able to put editing handles & resize any UI component easily.
After searching about a week I got this solution, so thought of sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you that you add a pinch gesture in those view to user can make zoom.

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *twoFingerPinch = 
  [[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scaleObject:)] autorelease];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:zoomGesture];
```

and the method:

```
- (void)scaleObject:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
  NSLog(@"Object scale: %f", recognizer.scale);
}
```

and change the object size with that scale. Moreover you can use other gestures like:

- UITapGestureRecognizer
- UIPinchGestureRecognizer
- UIRotationGestureRecognizer
- UISwipeGestureRecognizer
- UIPanGestureRecognizer
- UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Comment: If it comes to mobile devices pinch is the way to go. I suggest also to check if both fingers are inside UI component frame.

Comment: I thing UIPanGestureRecognizer will be more appropriate in my case.

Comment: If you consider user experience that Apple is fighting to give in every app, you shouldn't reinvent wheel and use proven solutions for mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you reject solution with pinch recognizer. I would suggest creating custom wrapper for UI components, that would create little squares in corners of the frame and in the middle of every side. Every square should have `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to control size of the object.

Comment: Pinch gesture is not appropriate in my case because it uses 2 finger touch and generally used for Zoom-in/Out. Pan gesture sounds ok for me . I'll give a try on this and let you know.